# Is there any documentation for the Log4cplus log properties files?

Tags: log4cplus

I've looked high and low and I can't find anything more than API docs which don't help at all with the log properties file.

I'm specifically looking for help with:

```
log4cplus.appender.SYSLOG=log4cplus::SysLogAppender  #if not commented out, this line causes failure
log4cplus.appender.SYSLOG.Threshold=DEBUG
log4cplus.appender.SYSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{%H:%M:%S} MyApp %m%n
log4cplus.appender.SYSLOG.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.SYSLOG.Facility=USER
```

But a reference of how to write these files would be SOOOO nice to have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

log4cplus configuration properties documentation is part of [`PropertyConfigurator`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PropertyConfigurator.html) documentation. There is also a separate documentation for the [`SysLogAppender`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1SysLogAppender.html).

Comment: Thank you, I think I just assumed the api docs only contained API things.